# Access HTTP GET from Java Client

Tags: java, web-services, http, get

I am trying to access HTTP GET from Java client:

```
public String getStreetAddressFromGeometry(String eventX, String eventY) {
    String streetName = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/revgeocode?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&location='"+eventX+"','"+eventY+"'");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String responseString;

        while ((responseString = br.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject rawObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                JSONArray searchResults = rawObj.getJSONArray("GeocodeInfo");
                for (int i = 0; i < searchResults.length(); i++) {

                    if(searchResults.getJSONObject(i).getString("BLOCK").equals("")){
                        streetName = searchResults.getJSONObject(i).getString("ROAD");
                    }else if (!searchResults.getJSONObject(i).getString("BLOCK").equals("")){
                        streetName = searchResults.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "BLOCK")
                                + " "
                                + searchResults.getJSONObject(i).getString("ROAD")
                                + " SINGAPORE "
                                + searchResults.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                        "POSTALCODE");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return "Error";
            }
        }

        conn.disconnect();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return streetName;
}
```

}

I am calling the one map API [here](http://www.onemap.sg/api/help/) under reverse geocode. I tried the URL with the current coordinates I've now and it's working fine on the test URL.

But when I put it into my codes and printed out the address returned. Instead of showing the address, it just state "Error" with no explanation or error message.

I wonder which part I did wrongly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Down voter mind to explain which part I did wrongly?

Comment: can you show us a working url for the service?

Comment: http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/revgeocode?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&location=41803.2,38210.8

Comment: that url gives me {"GeocodeInfo":[{"ErrorMessage":"Invalid Token"}]}

Comment: It was working fine on my side tho

Comment: Can the token only be used from certain IP addresses?

Comment: You're ignoring the exception.

Comment: Sorry my bad. @codebox Sorry I not really sure about the API but I guess it works for all IP addresses?

Comment: Place a debugger on the first line within the loop and try to discover what the initial value is for `responseString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the apostrophes from the `location` parameter, you don't have them in the valid url you posted:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/revgeocode?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&location="+eventX+","+eventY);
```

Also, there is probably more information about the problem in the Exception that gets thrown, but you are throwing that away and printing out 'Error', try `ex.printStackTrace();` instead.

Comment: Sorry my mistakes. I did print out the stack trace, it is showing no result for ROAD. But from the test URL, it did returned ROAD. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: As for the apostrophes, the eventX and eventY were String so  guess I should keep them?

Comment: No, you shouldnt have them in the url - try removing them

Comment: Sorry my bad. I mixed up the java and sql syntax :( . It's working now. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You are read response line by line and for every line you are tring to create jsonobject.
In my opinion You should first read all response, build one string from every line:

```
responseString += br.readLine()
```

and after that

```
JSONObject rawObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
...
```

Comment: Nope, no luck. It's still showing Error in my stack trace instead of the address returned from the API

Comment: The error message is no value for ROAD. but from the test URL, ROAD is the only thing returned other than coordX and coordY

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't help:

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
    return "Error";
}
```

Such code "swallows" the exception, leaving you clueless as to what the problem is. It's much better to throw the exception or rethrow it as a new exception with additional information (like the coordinate for which it failed).